# How do I make constraints match height of phone? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, constraints

Coming from `iOS` and `Xcode` I', confused about layout and constraints in `android studio`. My layout currently looks like this, which is fine for a small sized phone. But on a phone with a large height it leaves a big space at the bottom. I want the layout to follow and match the height of the phone.[image]

My `XML` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:theme="@style/NoBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
tools:context="com.sdc_nollvision_relative.myapp.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:text="DEMENSVÅRD"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subHeader"
    android:typeface="monospace"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="UTAN TVÅNG"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_header" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chapter1Header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chapter1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconHolder1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter1" />

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/iconHolder1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon1"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:civ_border_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter1" />

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/iconHolder2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon2"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/chapter1"
    app:civ_border_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter2" />

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/iconHolder3"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter3" />

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/iconHolder4"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter4" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/chapter1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundview"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subHeader" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chapter2Header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chapter2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconHolder2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter2" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/chapter2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundview"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chapter3Header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chapter3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconHolder3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter3" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/chapter3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundview"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chapter4Header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chapter4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconHolder4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter4" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/chapter4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundview"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/about_button"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/about"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/language_button"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/version_button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/version_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"

    android:text="version"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/language_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:text="language"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4" />
```

And yes, I'm aware that I have a fixed size of the buttons. But I have no idea how to make them dynamically follow the height of the phone. Sorry for such a basic question, but I'm still learning the basics here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a vertical chain with its `chainStyle` as `spread` or `spread_inside` to achieve what you want with little bit of margin and padding customizations for your top-most and bottom-most view(s).

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.stackoverflow.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_header"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:text="DEMENSVÅRD"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subHeader"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="UTAN TVÅNG"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chapter1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapter1Header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chapter1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconHolder1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter1" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconHolder1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon1"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:civ_border_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter1" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconHolder2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon2"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/chapter1"
        app:civ_border_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter2" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconHolder3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter3" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconHolder4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chapter1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/spinner_background"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chapter2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subHeader" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapter2Header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chapter2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconHolder2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chapter2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/spinner_background"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chapter3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapter3Header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chapter3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconHolder3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chapter3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/spinner_background"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chapter4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapter4Header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/chapter4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iconHolder4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chapter4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/spinner_background"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/about_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/about_button"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/language_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/version_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/version_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="version"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/language_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="language"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter4" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshots (for the above code):**

*1] For screen size - 5.0 inch (1080 x 1920 pixels) [Device: Nexus 5]*

[image]

*2] For screen size - 7.0 inch (1200 x 1920 pixels) [Device: Nexus 7]*

[image]

For more information on how to create a chain in `ConstraintLayout`, its proper usage and various chain styles please go through: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#Chains

I hope, this helps you.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for taking the time helping me out! :) Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a vertical chain of elements.
Check the detailed explanation here: https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb